# Angular2 change parent styles outside of component

Tags: css, angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I'd like to change the styles of a component outside the scope of my current component. The markup in my app.component.html is as follows:

```
<app-nav></app-nav>
<div id='content-container'>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

I'm looking to change the styles of a class `main-nav` in the app-nav component from the 'home-component' which is loaded from a route. I use `routerLink`'s in the nav and I've found if I add `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` to the `home.component.ts` I can alter the styles of the the class in the app-nav component however the changes are only applied once and if I go to other routes using the `routerLink`'s I cannot revert the changes (seems like the css is only loaded/applied once - when the component is initialized/comes into view)

Answer (score 2):

Special selectors are designed to access and apply css outside the encapsulation without having to change encapsulation scope. In your case I think :host or :host-context will help.

See https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#special-selectors

> Use the :host pseudo-class selector to target styles in the element
>   that hosts the component (as opposed to targeting elements inside the
>   component's template).

and

> Sometimes it's useful to apply styles based on some condition outside
>   of a component's view. For example, a CSS theme class could be applied
>   to the document  element, and you want to change how your
>   component looks based on that.
>
> Use the :host-context() pseudo-class selector, which works just like
>   the function form of :host(). The :host-context() selector looks for a
>   CSS class in any ancestor of the component host element, up to the
>   document root. The :host-context() selector is useful when combined
>   with another selector.

Answer (score 1):

> change the styles of a component outside the scope of my current component

Before I say anything else, this is highly discouraged. Components are supposed to be **self-contained entities**, which can be reusable across your project, or even other projects. By creating a component that changes something else in the system only through CSS, you're creating a tight coupling which is difficult to see immediately from code, leading to difficult-to-debug bugs and other errors.

If you want to change your `app-nav` (or `main-nav` as you refer to it later, I'm not sure if this is my mistake) based on the current route, you should do so by injecting the `ActivatedRoute` and querying it to determine the specific version of header which you want.

Another option is to simply move the header below the router outlet, so you always direct access to it from the component which rests across the whole page.

> the changes are only applied once and if I go to other routes using the routerLink's

This is expected, since the styles are injected into DOM only when you visit the actual component, no need for them to appear before there's need for it. Angular expects that the styles you define for a component and used *only* on that component. You're breaking this rule of thumb.

> I cannot revert the changes (seems like the css is only loaded/applied once - when the component is initialized/comes into view)

Your observation is correct.

Comment: The motivation for this was basically that I didn't want some style rules in the app-nav component to be used in all components for example: have the navigation opacity:0.5 when the home component is shown and its opacity:1 when any all other components are shown. Surely this is a common issue and I was just wondering if there was a better way to approach it?

Comment: When you mention 'Another option is to simply move the header below the router outlet', do you mean just nest the <app-nav> in the <router-outlet>? I've just tested this and tried to add a css rule targetting a class in the app-nav component in my home.component.css and it didn't work